# How do I sort a special JSON Discod.JS

Tags: javascript, json, sorting, discord

I did some research bit I can't find how to sort this file :

```js
{"228959972271194112":{"xp":3,"level":1},"458982747449589768":{"xp":26,"level":4},"539012914418548737":{"xp":0,"level":2}}
```

This file is called in my command file (I' making a Discord Bot with Discord.js) by :

```js
let xp = require("../xp.json");
```

I want to sort the IDs (Exemple : "228959972271194112") by levels (I do not care about XP) and all the answers I saw is sorting while the JSON start with a "var blabla = {..." and I do not have and I do not want a var at start.

Thank you for your help !

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> I want to sort the IDs (Exemple : "228959972271194112") by levels (I do not care about XP)

Hi, assuming you would like to have an array of the keys sorted in ascending order by the value of the level. You can first use the Object.keys to get an array of all the keys in the object. Then use the sort method and compare the value of level for each object. This will return an arrays of all the keys sorted in ascending order by the value of level.

```
let xp = require("../xp.json"); 
//{"228959972271194112":{"xp":3,"level":1},"458982747449589768":{"xp":26,"level":4},"539012914418548737":{"xp":0,"level":2}}
const sortedKeysByLevel = Object.keys(xp).sort((key1, key2) => xp[key1]['level'] - xp[key2]['level']); 
// ["228959972271194112", "539012914418548737", "458982747449589768"]
```

Comment: Thanks a lot and now, how can I deal with xp ? For thoses who have the same level

Comment: Great question. We can improve the sort function a little bit to check if the two levels equal 0. if they do we sort by xp if not we sort by level.
`const sortedKeysByLevel = Object.keys(xp).sort((key1, key2) => xp[key1]['level'] - xp[key2]['level'] === 0 ? xp[key1]['xp'] - xp[key2]['xp'] : xp[key1]['level'] - xp[key2]['level']);`

Comment: Omg I spent ten minuts to understand your code °0°. Well now I'd like to sort from the biggest to smallest, with the first line I could by replacing the - by + but now if I do will it meke unusuable the "=== 0 ?" ?

Comment: I figured out ! I inverted key1 and 2 ^^' ! so proud of me